# What is ffmpeg "rpt1" version?

Tags: apt, ffmpeg

When I run `apt-cache show ffmpeg`, there are two versions available.  One of them has "rpt1" on the end of the version number.  I can't find any info about this; what is the difference between the two?  And since they both have the same name, which one will be installed by `apt-get install ffmpeg`?

```
$ apt-cache show ffmpeg
Package: ffmpeg
Version: 7:3.2.10-1~deb9u1+rpt1
Architecture: armhf
Maintainer: Debian Multimedia Maintainers <pkg-multimedia-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Installed-Size: 2080
Depends: libavcodec57 (>= 7:3.2.10) | libavcodec-extra57 (>= 7:3.2.10), libavdevice57 (>= 7:3.2.10), libavfilter6 (>= 7:3.2.10) | libavfilter-extra6 (>= 7:3.2.10), libavformat57 (>= 7:3.2.10), libavresample3 (>= 7:3.2.10), libavutil55 (>= 7:3.2.10), libc6 (>= 2.7), libpostproc54 (>= 7:3.2.10), libsdl2-2.0-0 (>= 2.0.4), libswresample2 (>= 7:3.2.10), libswscale4 (>= 7:3.2.10), libva1 (>= 1.7.3)
Suggests: ffmpeg-doc
Breaks: libav-tools (<< 6:12~~), qt-faststart (<< 7:2.7.1-3~)
Replaces: libav-tools (<< 6:12~~), qt-faststart (<< 7:2.7.1-3~)
Multi-Arch: foreign
Homepage: https://ffmpeg.org/
Priority: optional
Section: video
Filename: pool/main/f/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_3.2.10-1~deb9u1+rpt1_armhf.deb
Size: 1516084
SHA256: 271a770685775a81d0bdff3c81de31515ae963644410053c44aa48dabd04ae56
SHA1: 1269504ecceeed06b32624a013f864e38f402ef9
MD5sum: 3a8eb30dedc14997a4ed3e48b6f7148f
Description: Tools for transcoding, streaming and playing of multimedia files
 FFmpeg is the leading multimedia framework, able to decode, encode, transcode,
 mux, demux, stream, filter and play pretty much anything that humans and
 machines have created. It supports the most obscure ancient formats up to the
 cutting edge.
 .
 This package contains:
  * ffmpeg: a command line tool to convert multimedia files between formats
  * ffserver: a multimedia streaming server for live broadcasts
  * ffplay: a simple media player based on SDL and the FFmpeg libraries
  * ffprobe: a simple multimedia stream analyzer
  * qt-faststart: a utility to rearrange Quicktime files
Description-md5: 032ff4ee68b923f5137379a7857cb8a8

Package: ffmpeg
Version: 7:3.2.10-1~deb9u1
Architecture: armhf
Maintainer: Debian Multimedia Maintainers <pkg-multimedia-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Installed-Size: 2080
Depends: libavcodec57 (>= 7:3.2.10) | libavcodec-extra57 (>= 7:3.2.10), libavdevice57 (>= 7:3.2.10), libavfilter6 (>= 7:3.2.10) | libavfilter-extra6 (>= 7:3.2.10), libavformat57 (>= 7:3.2.10), libavresample3 (>= 7:3.2.10), libavutil55 (>= 7:3.2.10), libc6 (>= 2.7), libpostproc54 (>= 7:3.2.10), libsdl2-2.0-0 (>= 2.0.4), libswresample2 (>= 7:3.2.10), libswscale4 (>= 7:3.2.10), libva1 (>= 1.7.3)
Suggests: ffmpeg-doc
Breaks: libav-tools (<< 6:12~~), qt-faststart (<< 7:2.7.1-3~)
Replaces: libav-tools (<< 6:12~~), qt-faststart (<< 7:2.7.1-3~)
Multi-Arch: foreign
Homepage: https://ffmpeg.org/
Priority: optional
Section: video
Filename: pool/main/f/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_3.2.10-1~deb9u1_armhf.deb
Size: 1515734
SHA256: 2286f467667016aeebd845e30a525cd3fe1addc4102acf2d58fc660f65ef72d0
SHA1: c683934a0b8fbae135f0c21cfded22da62f179b6
MD5sum: d883e2a2f7e08cd20fccaf1c78c2eb56
Description: Tools for transcoding, streaming and playing of multimedia files
 FFmpeg is the leading multimedia framework, able to decode, encode, transcode,
 mux, demux, stream, filter and play pretty much anything that humans and
 machines have created. It supports the most obscure ancient formats up to the
 cutting edge.
 .
 This package contains:
  * ffmpeg: a command line tool to convert multimedia files between formats
  * ffserver: a multimedia streaming server for live broadcasts
  * ffplay: a simple media player based on SDL and the FFmpeg libraries
  * ffprobe: a simple multimedia stream analyzer
  * qt-faststart: a utility to rearrange Quicktime files
Description-md5: 032ff4ee68b923f5137379a7857cb8a8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"+rpt1" indicates a package that has been modified by raspberry pi trading ltd. To find out exactly what they have changed you would have to look at the changelog in the package and/or download the source packages and debdiff them, but an educated guess is that they have modified it to enable some raspberry pi specific functionality.

Per [debian version number comparision rules](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/dpkg-dev/deb-version.5.en.html) 7:3.2.10-1~deb9u1+rpt1 > 7:3.2.10-1~deb9u1 , so all else being equal apt will choose 7:3.2.10-1~deb9u1+rpt1 over 7:3.2.10-1~deb9u1